# How should I structure a solution allowing direct repo access *and* a BLL layer?

Tags: c#, architecture

I was wondering whether there was a good established design pattern for sometimes allowing direct access from the presentation layer to one's repositories, but requiring the use of the BLL (because for certain data operations we want to impose business logic) for other methods.  The reason for direct access to the repositories is that if we didn't do this, we would have an enormous number of "pass-through" methods in a mandatory business logic layer that were pointless boilerplate, as we very often have no business logic to impose.  The following is a diagram of how the solution is currently structured:

[image: Architecture diagram]

How can we allow the presentation layer direct access to some, but not all, of the repositories?  We want certain actions to *have* to go through business logic.  Ideally this could be enforced so that developers couldn't accidentally just directly use the repositories for these methods.

Comment: "We would have an enormous number of "pass-through" methods in a mandatory business logic layer that were pointless boilerplate" I've had that exact same feeling myself.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but you are talking about a class that basically passes through to a repository or DAL, and then you are supposed to put "business logic" in these pass-thru methods? Can you add a pseudo-code example of this "business logic layer?"

Comment: I also would not consider the BLL a part of the infrastructure layer either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am all for answering a question as asked, because you probably have more information than you've described here, and it can be irrelevant for you to have to justify things you know are provably immovable in your situation anyway. I'll answer the question as asked, but first I want to point this out:

> The reason for direct access to the repositories is that if we didn't do this, we would have an enormous number of "pass-through" methods in a mandatory business logic layer that were pointless boilerplate, as we very often have no business logic to impose.

Your argument, when presented as it is in the question without further justification, is a massive red flag.

Whenever anyone argues skipping a layer, the same "it would be boilerplate" argument gets used over and over. I've seen several (5+) companies argue this for their project, only to then regret it when their specs change or when their codebase reaches the maintenance stage.

It's very common to think of your problem domain as a database model, and then write the codebase to support that database model. And in some cases, that's a good approach. But usually it isn't.

It's a good approach when there is no actual domain logic to speak of, e.g. if your application is a REST API which only exists to provide database access to some data resources.
It's *not* a good approach when you have actual domain logic in your codebase - even if *some* of the domain queries happen to be nothing more than a data query.

Instead, your domain (when one exists) should be **appreciably different** from the data layer. Your domain objects may resemble your data entities by having (a lot of) the same properties, but they each have their own different purpose, and you can't just mash these purposes together without any repercussions.

Trying to selectively opt in/out of a layer sounds like it's a clever way to avoid some situationally unnecessary extra lines of code. But more often than not, **clever bites you in the end**.
Whatever time you may have saved by not writing those few extra lines, you're going to lose more time when you have to migrate a no-domain query to a domain query, or vice versa.

That vice versa is important. If you argue that some queries should not use the domain, then all queries that fit that bill should not use the domain, and all queries that get change to no longer use the domain must be migrated.
If you argue "I don't *need* to migrate it, the domain just doesn't add anything, it's harmless", that proves that your initial reason for not wanting to use the domain when creating the query was a matter of laziness rather than algorithmical elegance or cleanliness.

So, the preferred answer here is **don't skip the domain layer, unless you can prove there's a genuine benefit other than laziness or meaninglessly trying to save a few lines of code**.

---

But I promised I'd answer the question as asked too, in case your requirements are truly immovable.

In any cleanly written codebase, your top level application (web project, in your case) creates a service provider which will inject all the dependencies.

Your service provider doesn't care about layers. If you ask for an `IFoo`, you're going to get the registered `IFoo` service. The service provider isn't going to throw an error because your layer isn't allowed to request a resource from the layer that `IFoo` is from. "Layer access rights" aren't a thing, as far as I'm aware at least.

This would give you what you want. Your top level application has direct control over which dependencies it requests, thereby making it possible to skip a layer when you want to.

Layers have their purpose, but in the end all the bits and pieces from all the referenced layers get mashed together into the same executable/runtime/service provider. This means that your top-level application has the final say over which layers/projects it directly uses.

But again, this is more often than not a bad idea.

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question, because if the top level application requests an `IContactsRepo`, it's gonna get all the contacts repo methods, even if I want to require 1 or 2 of them go through the business logic.  Also, it'd be good if you reworded the first half of your answer a bit to change emphasis; we're not saving "a few" lines of code by doing it this way; probably 95% of our calls don't require any business logic.

Comment: @Jez: Those "few lines" are per feature. I can't judge how many features you have. I can only judge how many lines it saves per feature. As a general tip, how you implement a given feature should not depend on how many other unrelated features there are. That makes no sense. That's like saying that your company laptop should have less components in it because there are many employees in your company. That makes no sense. A good laptop works the way it does, regardless of how many other laptops also exist alongside it.

Comment: @Jez _"if the top level application requests an IContactsRepo, it's gonna get all the contacts repo methods, even if I want to require 1 or 2 of them go through the business logic"_ Your outlook on how this works is... unorthodox. (a) If you want the ability to freely opt in/out of a layer, then you inherently sign up for the responsibility of choosing to opt in/out at the appropriate time. If you don't trust your developers to make the right decision, then you shouldn't be giving them the option to choose to begin with.

Comment: @Jez (b) It seems you think of your repository as a bag of static methods. That's just not how OOP works. When you ask for the repository, you're going to get the repository. It makes no sense to then expect it to somehow loop to the domain (it would be a circular reference). Instead, you should ask for the `IFooRepository` when you don't want the domain involved, and asked for the `IFooService` (which uses `IFooRepository` internally) when you _do_ want the domain involved. _(Note: for the naming used here, services are assumed to be the domain services)_.

Comment: Actually, the laptops analogy is a good one.  If you have a laptop with a bunch of extra components, the extra cost and resources used to build it is less of a problem in a company with 5 employees than in one with 500 employees, if everyone is getting a laptop.

Comment: @Jez: You argue between a laptop that has _too many_ part versus one that has the _right_ amount of parts. I argue between a laptop that has the _right_ amount of parts versus one that has _too few_. That's a subjective difference, but it does highlight how anyone who is already convinced that they should be cutting corners is likely to label the corner-but version as "normal", when it in fact is not.

Comment: @Jez: This is not an argument I'm going to persist, because there's no use in trying to explain the value of something to someone when they simply refuse the premise altogether. If you remain adamant about your corner cutting, then I can't stop you. Most people only learn good practice from suffering through bad practice, and they suffer through bad practice because they initially ignored the good practice advice because "they've figured out a clever shortcut" or thought the good practice was superfluous boilerplating. I was one of them. Most of us were. Are you going to be too?

Comment: I'm not necessarily disagreeing with the good practice argument.  But I do disagree with the idea that, if you're building something from scratch that's going to have lots of instances, the number of extra lines per instance shouldn't be multiplied by the number of instances to determine the extra cost of "doing it right".

Comment: @Jez: "Right" is not the same as "using less lines". The correctness of an implementation is independent of both the line count _and_ the feature count (and time needed to implement, for that matter). These things do all matter, but for independent and different reasons. The correctness of the implementation by itself is not affected by line count / feature count / time to implement, though the overall project management likely will be affected by them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116300/discussion-between-jez-and-flater).